# ROS Arduino Sabertooth Controller

Tags: c++, ros-kinetic, callback, raspberrypi, rasbperrypi

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,  I am trying to control a sabertooth 2x60 motor controller with an arduino interfaced to a raspberry pi using rosserial_arduino.  I have the connection working great, but whenever I try to publish a command to the topic that the arduino is subscribed to, the  sabertooth controller does nothing.  I can verify that the callback is working because of the receipt of various loginfo back to the terminal.  Also, I uploaded code to control the sabertooth (with no ROS), and it worked fine, so I know I have everything connected right.  Any ideas what is wrong/missing in the following code?  Thanks

```
#include <Sabertooth.h>
#include <ros.h>
#include <std_msgs/UInt16.h>

ros::NodeHandle nh;

Sabertooth ST(128);


void sabertooth_callback(const std_msgs::UInt16& cmd_msg){
  int power = cmd_msg.data;
  nh.loginfo("Got Command");
  // Ramp motor 1 from -127 to 127 (full reverse to full forward),
  // waiting 20 ms (1/50th of a second) per value.
  for (int power1 = -power; power1 <= 127; power1 ++)
  {
    ST.drive(power);
    delay(20);
    nh.loginfo("Got Command to Drive"); 
  }
  
  // Now go back the way we came.
  for (power = 127; power >= -127; power --)
  {
    ST.turn(power); // Tip for SyRen users: Typing ST.motor(power) does the same thing as ST.motor(1, power).
    nh.loginfo("Got Command to Turn"); 
    delay(20); 
  }
} 

ros::Subscriber<std_msgs::UInt16> sub("Sabertooth", sabertooth_callback);
    

void setup()
{ 
  ST.drive(0);
  ST.turn(0);
  SabertoothTXPinSerial.begin(9600); // 9600 is the default baud rate for Sabertooth packet serial.
  nh.initNode();
  nh.subscribe(sub);
}

void loop()
{
  nh.spinOnce();
}
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/281052/ros-arduino-sabertooth-controller/) by [nathanspotts](https://answers.ros.org/users/29622/nathanspotts/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2018-01-27

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tean chen](https://answers.ros.org/users/55007/tean-chen/) on 2020-05-18**:
dear

i want to make an autonomous indoor Mobile robot for my study, can you explain to me how to interface with hardware systems, I have Sabertooth 2X60 and Zed stereo Camera and Adruino Microcontroller and RPLIDAR. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have found that the Sabertooth software doesn't work with ROS. Just do a direct Serial.write instead. You'll lose the nice, similar number placement, but it will work. 1-127 is motor1, 128-255 is motor 2. Check out
https://github.com/avirtuos/ros_hercules/blob/master/src/hercules/arduino/hercules_rosserial/hercules_rosserial.ino

---

Originally posted by [Rodolfo8](https://answers.ros.org/users/18431/rodolfo8/) with karma: 299 on 2018-01-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [nathanspotts](https://answers.ros.org/users/29622/nathanspotts/) on 2018-01-28**:
Thanks for the response.  I figured there was something wrong with the Serial connection and reverted to using Sabertooth in RC mode.  However, I tried to use Serial.write and it didn't work as expected.  What version of serial do I need to put the Sabertooth in?  Simplified Serial or Packet Serial?

**Comment by [Rodolfo8](https://answers.ros.org/users/18431/rodolfo8/) on 2018-01-29**:
The Sabertooth should be in simplified serial mode. Use 9600 baud. Works perfectly. Did you check the sample code?

**Comment by [nathanspotts](https://answers.ros.org/users/29622/nathanspotts/) on 2018-01-29**:
That's what I tried to do.  I need to experiment a little more with it.  Do you use the tx and rx pins on the Arduino Uno.  Also, just checking that the SoftwareSerial Library is not needed.  How does writing 2 different values to serial.write work?  The second range doesn't overwrite the first?

**Comment by [Rodolfo8](https://answers.ros.org/users/18431/rodolfo8/) on 2018-01-29**:
Mine is a Mega. I use TX2 which is #16. So my commands are Serial2.write. Like this:
if (millis() > motorTimer + MOTOR_TIMEOUT_MS) {
Serial2.write(64); // apply brakes
Serial2.write(192);
}
else {
Serial2.write(pwrLeft); // motor speed
Serial2.write(pwrRight);

**Comment by [nathanspotts](https://answers.ros.org/users/29622/nathanspotts/) on 2018-01-29**:
Thanks so much for your help.  That makes complete sense to me.  I'll see if I can get it set up and working later today.

**Comment by [nathanspotts](https://answers.ros.org/users/29622/nathanspotts/) on 2018-01-30**:
Well, for others with this same issue using the Arduino Uno, I couldn't get it to work on pins 0 and 1 (Rx, Tx).  I had to include the library SoftwareSerial and assign different pins for the communication (for me I used 10 & 11, but only the Tx is needed).  Then it worked great!